# The dimensions of a character's box vs what is in the .afm and .tfm files

Tags: fonts, positioning, boxes

For definiteness, let's suppose we use `pdfLaTeX` to compile this:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.0001pt}
\fbox{a}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

I do understand that there are good reasons why the displayed box is not the true bounding box (in particular, the top and bottom of the glyph stick out, while there are gaps between the glyph and the left and right sides of the box).

On the other hand, this is a glyph from `lmr10.pfb` (I know this because `pdffonts` tells me the font is `LMRoman10-Regular`, while `lm.map` contains the line

```
cs-lmr10 LMRoman10-Regular "enclmcs ReEncodeFont" <lm-cs.enc <lmr10.pfb
```

When I inspect `lmr10.afm`, I see the line

```
C 97 ; WX 500 ; N a ; B 32 -11 483 448 ;
```

and when I inspect `cs-lmr10.vpl` (generated from `cs-lmr10.tfm` by `tftopl`), there is this:

```
(CHARACTER C a
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.445274)
   (CHARIC R 0.010777)
```

Finally, I can inspect `lmr10.pfb` in `FontForge`, and it turns out that the values listed in `lmr10.afm` are the dimensions of the true bounding box of the glyph 'a': in `FontForge`, the leftmost point of the glyph has the *x*-coordinate 32, the lowest point has the *y*-coordinate -11, the rightmost point has the *x*-coordinate 483, and the highest point has the *y*-coordinate 448.

As best as I can tell, the values listed in `cs-lmr10.vpl` give the width of the box produced by `\fbox{a}`, but not the height. This can be inspected visually; but also, using  `\heightof` from `calc` package, we get that the height is 4.3056 pt.

Just in case there is some question whether all of this is some artifact of `\fbox`, we can also perform these measurements: `\heightof{\mbox{a}}`, `\heightof{\hbox{a}}`, `\heightof{a}`, and `\widthof{\mbox{a}}`, `\widthof{\hbox{a}}`, `\widthof{a}`. All the heights come out as 4.3055 pt, and all the widths as 5.0 pt.

**My questions:**

1. How does LaTeX determine the geometry of the box produced by `\fbox`? For example, where does this 4.3056 pt for the height come from? If—as it appears to be the case—it does not come from either the .afm file or the .tfm file, then where does it come from?
2. Is it possible, in LaTeX, to put 'a' in a box (not necessarily a framed one) that coincides with the true bounding box of the glyph? Can we use it to do the following:  when we use the `\put(10,10)` command to place that box (which contains the visible glyph 'a') on a page, what ends up at the coordinate (10,10) is the lower-left corner of the true bounding box of the glyph? Another thing that should happen is that when we apply `\heghtof` and `\widthof` to that box, we get the height and width of the true bounding box of the glyph.

(Of course, what I mean is, can we do the above using only the internal resources of LaTeX, no matter what font we are using? We shouldn't have to figure out, every time and for every glyph that interests us, which font it came from and then go look at the appropriate .afm file ourselves and set the coordinates in the LaTeX document by hand.)

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at rm-lmr10 not cs-lmr10,

A modified version of your test file

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.0001pt}
\fbox{a}

\sbox0{a}
\typeout{box:
\the\ht0,
\the\dp0,
\the\wd0}
\typeout{tfm:
\the\fontcharht\font`a,
\the\fontchardp\font`a,
\the\fontcharwd\font`a}
\typeout{font:\the\font}
\typeout{meaning:\expandafter\meaning\the\font}
```

Produces terminal output of

```
box: 4.3055pt, 0.0pt, 5.0pt
tfm: 4.3055pt, 0.0pt, 5.0pt
font:\OT1/lmr/m/n/10 
meaning:select font rm-lmr10
```

note the final `rm-lmr10`.

Then `tfopl rm-lmr10.tfm` produces

```
(CHARACTER C a
   (CHARWD R 0.5)
   (CHARHT R 0.43055)
   (CHARIC R 0.010777)
```

with the width and height exactly matching the dimensions that you see from TeX.

Comment: Thank you! (I should have deduced this also from the log file, which mentions `lm-rm.enc`; then `grep lmr10.pfb $(kpsewhich pdftex.map) | grep lm-rm.enc` gives a line that begins with `rm-lmr10`.)

Comment: As far as the second question I posed: am I to understand that there seems to be no practical, automatic way, within pdfLaTeX (or even LuaLaTeX), to get access to the true visual bounding box of a character, such as that given in the file `lmr10.afm`?

Comment: @linguisticturn certainly tex has no access to the visual character, `a` could be a solid black rectangle as far as it can tell, what I can't exactly see is where the tfm metrics came from compared to afm, but they may have been adjusted by hand in comparison to the cmr10 tfm metrics, anyway they are by now what they are.

Comment: BTW, I just looked at what happens if we use LuaLaTeX and `\usepackage{fontspec}` with `\setmainfont{Latin Modern Roman}`. In this case, `\ht` and `\dp` of a box containing a single glyph **do** correspond to the numbers given in the afm file. But `\wd` still gives the distance between the left and the right side-bearing boundaries of the glyph, same as in pdfLaTeX.